# Subpage with setting api wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, settings

I'm currently trying to get my head around the settings api, which is been a bit of a struggle to be honest.

The problem I am having is that when I submit the form on the subpage, it just goes to the the options.php page?

Here is my code so far

```
function setup_theme_admin_menus() {  


add_menu_page('Theme settings', 'SMate Options', 'manage_options',   
    'theme_settings', 'theme_settings_page');  

add_submenu_page('theme_settings',   
    'Front Page Elements', 'Front Page', 'manage_options',   
    'theme_settings_fp', 'theme_front_page_settings'); 

    add_submenu_page(
    'theme_settings',   
    'Team Option', 
    'Team Option', 
    'manage_options',   
    'theme_team_options', 
    'theme_team_settings_fn'
    );  
}


add_action('admin_init', 'initialize_theme_options'); 


function initialize_theme_options(){

register_setting('team_details', 'team_details' );

add_settings_section( 
    'member1',         
    'MEMBER 1',                  
    'theme_settings_fn', 
    'theme_team_options'
); 

add_settings_field(   
    't1',                  
    'Name',                 
    'text_fn',                       
    'theme_settings_team',
    'member1'
); 
add_settings_field(   
    'jt1',        
    'Job',      
    'text_fn',    
    'theme_settings_team', 
    'member1' 
);  
add_settings_field(   
    'lt1',
    'Description',  
    'longtext_fn',  
    'theme_settings_team',
    'member1' 
);
}

add_action('admin_init', 'initialize_theme_options');


function theme_team_settings_fn() { 


?>  

    <div class="wrap">  


        <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>  
        <h2>Sandbox Theme Options</h2>  


        <?php print_r('team_details');
         settings_errors(); ?>


        <form method="post" action="options.php">  
            <?php do_settings_sections('theme_team_options'); ?> 
            <?php submit_button(); ?>  
        </form>  

    </div><!-- /.wrap -->  
<?php  


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I seem to have hit a brick wall and all tutorials seem to go through using add_theme_page

Comment: you are missing a few key elements to make your sub-page work, it doesnt matter its a sub page or theme page. You are on the right path and do set the form action to options.php because you want to create items that go into the options table in the sql db.

Comment: thanks for that, I can understand that my elements may not be posting, I just cant understand that when I submit, it redirects me to /options.php?

Answer (score 0):

For starters your `register_settings('option_group','option_name);` shouldn't be the same name I would do `team_details_group` and maybe `team_details_options`, etc.

Then do `settings_fields('team_details_group')` right inside the form after the

`<form method=post action=options.php>`

followed immediately by `$options = get_option('team_details_options')`

then use `team_details_options` to inside the input fields name attribute to save any data i.e:

`<input type="text" name="team_details_options[memberName]" />`

Let me know if this helps or you need more information.